# Do I stand a chance of receiving a research internship at a 3.57 GPA?

Tags: internship, gpa, international

I am an undergraduate who will be looking for winter and summer research internships next year. My current GPA is 3.57/4 and have two excellent quality research papers written as a first author. I wanted to ask if I stand any chance for the internship I am looking for (it is at a T15 school for mathematics) The professor (say Mr. X) under whom I am looking for an internship is an alumnus of my school and has good connections with the professors of my college so I can expect really good LORs from them. Apart from that, the research papers I've written as exactly in line with the research work of Mr.X's work. I'm worried about the GPA. I can definitely improve it to a 3.7 maybe but I'm unsure if that's still enough or not.

Comment: Nobody here can answer that. Maybe. Possibly. We don't know any better than you do. Sorry. Good luck.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you Buffy for your response. I'm assuming that research internships are extremely unpredictable and no one can exactly predict whether you'll get into the internship or not.

Comment: Reviewing applications is a *pain*. Tons of work, tons of time. If they felt they could make it easier by saying "only apply if your GPA is 3.7 or greater", they would, to save their time as much as yours. If it's not that simple, then the only way to find out for both you and them is to go through the application.

Comment: As an aside, if you think about your professors as "Mr. X", you may want to work academic social etiquette to avoid needlessly antagonizing people when applying for positions. A "Dr. X" or "Professor X" would be a more appropriate title.

Answer (score 0):

Even though no one here can say with 100% surety or guarantee your placement, your profile seems to be a good one if not the ideal. That could enhance your chances of selection. You have good grades, research exposure, letter of recommendations and so on. But bear in mind that there is always a pool of applicants out of which you have to stand out. So, even if you are not selected, you should take it positively.

I wish you good luck!

Comment: I understand it! I can agree that it may not be the perfect profile that the professors are looking for but hopefully something works out. Thank you for your kind words.